# 'created the "A" programme' or 'created the programme'

Tags: grammar

These sentences are grammatically correct?

> 1. Participated in project work on the "A" system and **created the "A"   programme**.
> 2. Participated in project work on the "A" system and
>       **created the programme**.

Thank you in advance.

P.S.
"A" - name of application/program

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but the first accounts for the detail of which program, so I'd use that. If you'd like to show which programme the person in question made without repeating the name, you could use:

> Participated in project work on the "A" system and created the programme for said system.

Just a quick note-- it seems like A is a computer program. If so, then we use the spelling *program* (*programme* is for pamphlet type things, or listings.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.  1 is very clear and 2 should be changed unless you have context making things obvious.

With 1, it's redundant to say "A" system and "A" programme, but not so redundant that it's jarring - a reader/listener would gather that you are trying to make it clear that you did both things related to "A".

With 2, I would change it to:

> Participated in project work on the "A" system and created *its* programme.

unless its obvious by way of context to the reader/listener that you could work on the "A" system and also create "A"'s program.  If in doubt, change it.